# debug grails in vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, grails, breakpoints

I know, that this question is well discussed in this and many other places but none of the solutions works for me. To keep it short, I won't explain all the things I found as possible solution I found in the past days, so I ask for a walkthrough that works.

I want to be able to debug a grails-app within Visual Studio Code.

1. Create a launch.json like this:

`{    "version": "0.2.0",      "configurations": [ {      "type": "pwa-chrome",                "request": "launch",                "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",                "url": "http://192.168.1.54:8080/test1/",                "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",                "sourceMaps": true             }           ] }`

2. run the app (grails run-app)
3. set a breakpoint and start the debugger within vscode.

The browser will start (in this case chrome) but breakpoints won't work at all. They are marked as 'unbound breakpoints'. I use VSCode 1.66.0 Node.js 16.13.0 on Windows 10. If any other details are nedded to answer my questeion, please let me know!

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: At the moment I work with grails 5.1.5.

Comment: I don't know how the vscode config you show there relates but instead of `grails run-app` if you ran `grails run-app --debug-jvm`, by default that will start the debug agent on port 5005 and it will be configured in `suspend:y` mode so you can connect a remote debugger to the agent.

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your answer! As I mentioned, I read a lot before I posted my question. the --debug-jvm-switch was one of that. But what is a remote debugger and how do i connect it? Is it a simple browser connected on that port? how can I use breakpoints and watches there? I didn't find a howto in the doku...

Comment: "But what is a remote debugger and how do i connect it?" - A remote debugger is a debugger that is running in a separate process than the the thing being debugged, possibly even on a different machine.  When you run with `--debug-jvm` that starts the agent in your application that will listen for the debugger to attach.  I do not know how to start up a remote debugger in VSCode but that is a really fundamental thing and I am sure VSCode supports it.

Comment: Netbeans can do what you want to do.  It can debug with breakpoint and watch variable with a click of a button.  Want to switch to Netbeans?

Comment: Thank you tom6502! I know Netbeans but I didn't want to change the editor as I am familiar with VS Code and for some other reason that would lead much to far. My goal is debuggin in VS Code. Unfortunately I cannot get it running as desired. For my next project I think about following your suggestion...